# Programatically creating an AD account through secure LDAP

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Currently I'm successfully creating AD accounts through C# via an LDAP connection using the PrincipalContext. I create a new UserPrincipal, apply the various properties as required and call save()

Essentially something like this

```
using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
  using(var up = new UserPrincipal(pc))
  {
    up.SamAccountName = "whatever";
    up.EmailAddress = "test@example.com";
    up.SetPassword(password);
    up.Enabled = true;
    up.Save();
  }
}
```

All works fine but now we need to do the same thing over a secure LDAP connection and I'm struggling to find any info online regarding the specifics of how to do this. This makes me think that perhaps there's no difference from how I'm currently doing and instead all I need do is make sure the server supports LDAPS and is configured to use it.

Perhaps SO is wrong forum for this, am happy to move the question to a different forum if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default TCP port for LDAP is 389. That's what's used if you don't tell it otherwise. To use LDAPS, you have to specify the LDAPS port of 636. For example:

```
using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "example.com:636"))
```

Where `example.com` is your domain name.

However, using LDAPS requires that your computer trusts the SSL certificate that the server uses. Sometimes a self-signed cert is used and that will cause this to fail. `PrincipalContext` doesn't report certificate errors. It reports it as if the server could not be contacted. So if you have an issue there, you can use this PowerShell script to download the certificate and inspect it:

```
$webRequest = [Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://example.com:636")
try { $webRequest.GetResponse() } catch {}
$cert = $webRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate
$bytes = $cert.Export([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Cert)
set-content -value $bytes -encoding byte -path "certificate.cer"
```

Change the first line to have your domain name. If that works, there will be a file called `certificate.cer` that you can double-click on and inspect. If your computer doesn't trust it, you will see a message saying so. If that is a problem, you probably just need to install the root certificate as a "Trusted Root Certificate" on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. REgarding the certs....if I'm deploying this to a server that trusts the LDAPS server's cert, should this be ok and not cause problems?